# cannot find type or namespace "SafeIntDictionary"

Tags: c#, dictionary, type-safety

While I compile PexExtension, i run into an error in line line

```
SafeIntDictionary<int> undoMarkers = new SafeIntDictionary<int>();
```

The compiler shows "error 6  cannot find type or namespace "SafeIntDictionary" (whether lack of using instructor or assembly?)

I compile it using visual studio 2010.

> 错误    6   未能找到类型或命名空间名称“SafeIntDictionary”(是否缺少 using
>   指令或程序集引用?)    E:\docs\Colected papers\Loop
>   Invariant\tools\PexExtensions\Sources\DySy\Engine\DySyPathAnalyzer.cs 257 13  DySy
>   (DySy\DySy)

Comment: I assume you're trying to use the ExtendedRefection collection from `Microsoft.ExtendedReflection.Collections`. Did you include the using statement? (`using Microsoft.ExtendedReflection.Collections;')

Answer (score 1):

What namespace does this come from?  Do you have it declared in a `using` statement in that code file?  Also, do you have it added as a **Reference** in your project?  If both of those requirements are not met, you will receive an error like you have.